# plotting line graph with two lines in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a simple double line graph with a dataset I made. Here's the data:

```
date <- c("2021-04-06","2021-04-10", "2021-04-14", "2021-04-18")
as.Date(date)
graded <- c(3408, 3572, 3647, 3864)
psa10 <- c(2099, 2130, 2147, 2193)

graded_marvel <- data.frame(date, graded, psa10)
graded_marvel
```

And here's what I did to try and graph this

```
library("ggplot2")
graph <- ggplot(graded_marvel, aes(date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = graded), color = "darkred") +
  geom_line(aes(y = psa10), color = "blue")

print(graph)
```

All I get is an empty graph that has the correct values on the axes, but the graph just comes up empty. Not sure what to do. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your `date` variable is not a date, so ggplot2 interprets is as a character and assigns a discrete x scale. This auto-groups your data based on the x-axis value, so every 'group' only has one observations, with which you cannot draw a line. The way to fix this is to convert your date to a proper `Date` class.

```r
library(ggplot2)

date <- c("2021-04-06","2021-04-10", "2021-04-14", "2021-04-18")
graded <- c(3408, 3572, 3647, 3864)
psa10 <- c(2099, 2130, 2147, 2193)

graded_marvel <- data.frame(date, graded, psa10)

ggplot(graded_marvel, aes(as.Date(date))) +
  geom_line(aes(y = graded), color = "darkred") +
  geom_line(aes(y = psa10), color = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Very nice teunbrand. Mine is a little overcomplicated I guess?!

Comment: Oh I think your answer is a perfectly fine solution. (at the time of writing) it only misses the explanation of why OP's lines didn't show up in the plot: the problem wasn't that the data was in wide format (though I agree that long format is better). The problem was indeed the `group` variable which has been automatically been set by ggplot2 due to it interpreting the date as a categorical variable.

Answer (score 0):

First get long format with `pivot_longer`.
Then plot with `ggplot2`.

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(date), y = values, group = names)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=names)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=names, color=names)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("darkred", "blue"))
```

data:

```
df <- graded_marvel %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -date,
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  )
```

[image]